# php_mssql.dll support for php version greater >= 5.3

Tags: php, sql-server, visual-c++-6, visual-c++-2008

PHP has removed support for `php_mssql.dll` support for versions starting with 5.3. For that reason I have been using version 5.2 till now. But `ionCube` which converts PHP application into binary format, has also removed support for VC6.

So, I have move to PHP version which is greater than 5.2, since it does not support VC9. But version greater than 5.3 does not have `php_mssql.dll`, which means I will have to convert all the `mssql_` calls to `sqlsrv_`.

But that is not feasible. Is there a way to be able to use `php_mssql.dll` with PHP 5.3 (VC9 compiled)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The MSSQL lib for PHP >= 5.3 is included in the `php5-sybase` package.

An even better approach would be to use Microsoft's PHP API to connect. If you install their package, it will give you a .dll file similiar to `php_sqlsrvXX.dll`.

See the following links:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/mt683517.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn865013.aspx

https://github.com/azure/msphpsql

Personally I suggest you to upgrade to PHP 5.6 and use the Microsoft SQL driver in combination with PDO.